# Trigonometric Identities: Given $\cot(b)=-2$ find $\sin(4b)$ and $\cos(4b)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $\cot(b)=-2$ find $\sin(4b)$ and $\cos(4b)$

I found $\sin(4b)$ as $-24/25$ but I always get a very bad answer for $\cos(4b)$

Any hints?

edit:

I made $sin(4b)$ into a expanded form.

$4sin(b)cos^3(b)-4sin^3(b)cos(b)$
And then I made a triangle using $cot(b)=-2$ for information.

I got from that triangle that, $sin(b)=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$ and that $cos(b)=\frac{-2\sqrt{5}}{5}$

And from their I simplified.

But whenever I expand $cos(4b)$ and plug in I get a bad answer, $\frac{353}{25}$ and I do not know if it is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The result $353/25$ is surely wrong, as a cosine cannot be $>1$.

You're complicating your own life! `;-)`

There are standard formulas:
\begin{align}
\sin 2x&=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{2\cot x}{\cot^2x+1}
\\[4px]
\cos 2x&=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{\cot^2x-1}{\cot^2x+1}
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\sin 2b=\frac{-4}{4+1}=-\frac{4}{5}
$$
and
$$
\cos 2b=\frac{4-1}{4+1}=\frac{3}{5}
$$
Now you know that
\begin{align}
\sin 4b&=2\sin2b\cos2b=-\frac{24}{25} \\[4px]
\cos 4b&=\cos^22b-\sin^22b=…
\end{align}

Comment: Yes but what did you get for $cos(4b)$, I got $\frac{353}{25}$ and I don't think that is correct.

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou Since $3^2-(-4)^2=-7$, the answer is $-\frac{7}{25}$. I don't know how you find $353$.

Comment: Oh i see what you did now, thanks!

Comment: No i got -7/25 too using your method, but for some reason, when i first did the math i got cos(2b) wrong